# imageswitcher fills screen (but I dont want it to do that) [android]

Tags: java, android, scale, imageswitcher

I have added an imageswitcher to my register fragment, when the user select his/her gender the image changes but the image shown is too big and I cant scale it. I am using a scrollview and it is not good that the Imageswitcher is bigger than screen. I tried using smaller images but the result is same. Here is my XML:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/registerbackground"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/kayit_kayit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/register"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/kayit_ad"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:hint="@string/hintAd"
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/kayit_soyad"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:hint="@string/hintSoyad"
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/kayit_email"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:hint="@string/hintEmail"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio0"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:text="@string/kayitKiz"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:text="@string/kayitErkek"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF" />

            </RadioGroup>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageSwitcher    
                android:id="@+id/cinsiyetSwitcher"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </ImageSwitcher>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText 
                android:id="@+id/kayit_kelime1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:hint="@string/hintKelimeler1"
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"/>

            <EditText 
                android:id="@+id/kayit_kelime2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="@string/hintKelimeler2"
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"/>

            <EditText 
                android:id="@+id/kayit_kelime3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:hint="@string/hintKelimeler3"
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"/>

        </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

and the code for the imageswitcher:

```
....

cinsiyetSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cinsiyetSwitcher);
            cinsiyetSwitcher.setFactory(new ViewFactory() {

                   @Override
                   public View makeView() {
                       ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
                       imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
                       imageView.setLayoutParams(new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                       return imageView;
                       }

                   });

            kizRadio = (RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.radio0);
            erkekRadio = (RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.radio1);

            kizRadio.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        degistir1(v);
                    }
            });

            erkekRadio.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    degistir2(v);
                }
            });

....
```

...

```
public void degistir1(View view)
{
      Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),
      android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
      Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),
      android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
      cinsiyetSwitcher.setInAnimation(in);
      cinsiyetSwitcher.setOutAnimation(out);
      cinsiyetSwitcher.setImageResource(R.drawable.kari);
}

public void degistir2(View view)
{
      Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),
      android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
      Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),
      android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
      cinsiyetSwitcher.setInAnimation(out);
      cinsiyetSwitcher.setOutAnimation(in);
      cinsiyetSwitcher.setImageResource(R.drawable.adam);
}
```

Comment: Change the `ImageSwitchers` width to `wrap_content`

Comment: Didnt helped. I added code to scale it in .java file. It scaled the images but the Imageswitcher is still big. there is a big space before and after imageswitcher.

Comment: It's because you wrap every view in a LinearLayout which is wrong

Comment: Hmm, what should I do instead?

Comment: Remove all ViewGroups (LinearLayout) with 1 child view, and move the gravity and padding/margin to the view itself.

Comment: It is too much work for me :D but it sounds like a correct answer :D